# Is it possible to relocate all packages excluding the only one without specifying all

Tags: gradle, shadowjar, gradle-shadow-plugin

As I can see `ConfigureShadowRelocation` task does not support excludes.
`ShadowJar` task does not support patterns in `relocate` method. I use version 7.1.2.

Is there a way to do a bulk relocation with excludes? Maybe I missed something.

UPD: Here is an example:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":lib-b"))

    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0")
}

tasks.withType<ShadowJar> {
    archiveClassifier.set("")
    relocate("my.example", "shaded.example") {
        exclude("my.example.api.*")
    }
    relocate("okhttp3", "shaded.okhttp3")
    relocate("com.fasterxml.jackson", "shaded.jackson")
}
```

In the example `lib-b` brings the only transitive dependency `com.fasterxml.jackson`. But in a real scenario there might be lots of them. I wonder if there is a way not to specify them all in `relocate` method.

Comment: Please provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you are trying to achieve.